# Select highest aggregated group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, ssms, window-functions

I'm having trouble with selecting the highest aggregated group.

I have data in a table like this: `Sales` table:

| ID | GroupDescription | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Group1 | 2 |
| 1 | Group1 | 15 |
| 1 | Group2 | 3 |
| 1 | Group3 | 2 |
| 1 | Group3 | 2 |
| 1 | Group3 | 2 |
| 2 | Group1 | 2 |
| 2 | Group2 | 5 |
| 2 | Group3 | 3 |
| 2 | Group4 | 12 |
| 2 | Group4 | 2 |
| 2 | Group4 | 2 |

I want to return 1 record for each ID. I also want to include the Group that had the most sales and the total sales for that group and ID.

Expected output:

| ID | GroupDescription | SumSales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Group1 | 17 |
| 2 | Group4 | 16 |

I have code working but I feel like it can be written much better:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, SumSales DESC) as RowNum, * FROM
    (
        SELECT
        ID 
        ,GroupDescription
        ,SUM(Sales) OVER(PARTITION BY ID,GroupDescription) as SumSales 
        FROM Sales
        ) t1
    ) t2
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate by `ID` and `GroupDescription` and use window functions `FIRST_VALUE()` and `MAX()` to get the top group and its total:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,
       FIRST_VALUE(GroupDescription) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SUM(Sales) DESC) GroupDescription,
       MAX(SUM(Sales)) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) SumSales
FROM Sales
GROUP BY ID, GroupDescription;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6b177f45badc8731636b7c0c5b4d58c9).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could use normal aggregation in the inner table. You can also put the row-number on the same level as that.

```sql
SELECT
  s.ID
  ,s.GroupDescription
  ,s.SumSales
FROM
(
    SELECT
      s.ID
      ,s.GroupDescription
      ,SUM(s.Sales) as SumSales
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.ID ORDER BY SUM(s.Sales) DESC) as RowNum
    FROM Sales s
    GROUP BY
      s.ID
      ,s.GroupDescription
) s
WHERE s.RowNum = 1;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80bfd209e7e916e6e6c1c65af8cb79bb)

Note that ordering a window function by the same column as the partitioning makes no sense, and will be ignored.